# Алгоритм исключения ненужных чисел

Tags: java, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как составить алгоритм по заданию?

Задание:

> В американской армии считается несчастливым число 13, а в японской — 4. Перед международными учениями штаб российской армии решил исключить номера боевой техники, содержащие числа 4 или 13 (например, 40123, 13313, 12345 или 13040), чтобы не смущать иностранных коллег. Если в распоряжении армии имеется 100 тыс. единиц боевой техники и каждая боевая машина имеет номер от 00001 до 99999, то сколько всего номеров придётся исключить?

Comment: хех, а 100-тысячную боевую машину уворовали небось? ;)

Comment: Вы сформулируйте, на выходе что должно быть ? Все "хорошие","плохие",количество ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А может мне сделать для вас эту задачку поинтереснее?? ))) По старой памяти, когда преподавал информатику, я давал подобное, но не на 2 числа. Но у вас интереснее. Описываю ход решения с одним числом, а дальше попробуйте понять, как решить второе и общее между ними. Но это, если только интересно. Как выше написал

> -fogbit- В [0:20] - 2 раза (4 и 14). В [0:30] - 3 раза (0, 14, 24), [0:100] -
> 11 раз и т.д. (Только 0-100 не 11 а 19 раз... Человек забыл посчитать, кроме числа 44 еще и 41..42....49)

Отсюда легко вывести формулу для 10 в степени x (это наше конечное число) варианты повторений числа y (однозначного отличного от нуля))) составит

`9^(х-1)*10^0 + 9^(х-2)*10^1+ 9^(х-3)*10^2... до 9^0*10^х-1`

(это вам подсказка, из которой можно сделать спокойно цикл). Дальше подсказывать, как разложить так же по числу 13? И потом найти общие точки? (Это самое сложное, но и самое интересное.)

Answer (score 3):

Если можно просто перебором, то тогда лучше проверять не просто на наличие 1,3, а на наличие "13", например, регулярным выражением.

```java
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 99999; i++) {
    if (("" + i).matches(".*(4|13).*")) {
        c++;
    }
}
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: Кстати, на [0:100] - 19 раз встречается, так как еще десяток чисел [40:49]

Comment: На практике конечно перебор (техника сейчас быстрая), а если мозги размять, тогда комбинаторика.

Comment: Согласен, интересная задачка, только сейчас времени подумать нет =)

Answer (score 2):

Подумайте над тем фактом, что в последовательности чисел от 0 до 10 символ "4" встречается ровно 1 раз. В [0:20] - 2 раза (4 и 14). В [0:30] - 3 раза (4, 14, 24), [0:100] - 11 раз и т.д.

Comment: Ха-ха, а с 40 до 49 ?

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема-то? Запускаете цикл от 1 до 99999: на каждом шаге преобразуете число в строку и в строке проверяете наличие в ней 1,3 и 4. Если все есть, инкрементируете счетчик.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "Artem Prigoda"

Comment: Помните только, что 1 и 3 числа должны быть подряд при проверке!!! Но за такой ответ я бы убил, когда давал задачу на определение, сколько чисел содержат шестерку, если считать от 1 до 1000. В вашем случае тоже с одним числом можно решить простой формулой, но с двузначным числом такое не прокатит и надо будет еще учитывать, сколько совпадут (сколько одновременно содержат оба числа), так что пока оптимально, но тупо перебором можно получить ответ.

Comment: >но за такой ответ я бы убил когда давал задачу
аналогично.

Answer (score 1):

имхо простое и достаточно гибкое решение, - позволяет подсунуть любые фильтры которые только взбредут в голову. нет смысла генерировать число а потом подсчитывать значения его отдельных разрядов. конвертация в строку тоже ресурсоемкая операция. а ведь можно сразу генерировать число в том виде который нам нужен:
`a*1 + b*10 + c*100 + ...`

рекурсивно генерируем значения для всех разрядов числа (вложеность рекурсии = количество разрядов). режим читов включен!

и сам код:

```
import java.util.LinkedList ;
import java.util.List ;

public class DigitFilter
{
    // создаем интерфейс для фильтрации ненужных чисел    
    interface Filter
    {
        // метод принимает переменное число аргументов типов int,
        // комилятор неявно их преобразует к int []
        public boolean suite ( long... args ) ;
    }

    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        // создаем фильтры
        final List < Filter > filters = new LinkedList < Filter > () ;
        filters.add ( createJapanFilter () ) ;
        filters.add ( createUSAFilter () ) ;

        // задаем количество знаков в числе
        // это число ограничено лишь максимальной вложеностью рекусии (256)
        final long order = 2 ;

        // выполняем рекурсивный поиск
        // количество обработаных позиций не передаем, пока-что их нет
        find ( filters, order ) ;
    }

    private static Filter createJapanFilter ()
    {
        return new Filter ()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean suite ( final long... args )
            {
                // пустой массив нет смысла проверять
                if ( (null == args) || (0 == args.length) )
                {
                    return true ;
                }

                // проверяем самый младший разряд числа, все старшие уже проверены
                return (4 != args[args.length - 1]) ;
            }
        } ;
    }

    private static Filter createUSAFilter ()
    {
        return new Filter ()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean suite ( final long... args )
            {
                // пустой массив нет смысла проверять
                // если в нем только 1 разряд - тоже
                if ( (null == args) || (0 == args.length) || (1 == args.length) )
                {
                    return true ;
                }

                // проверяем на 13, - предпоследний != 1 и последний 3
                if ( (1 == args[args.length - 2]) && (3 == args[args.length - 1]) )
                {
                    return false ;
                }

                return true ;
            }
        } ;
    }

    private static void find ( final List < Filter > filters, final long order, final long... args )
    {
        // все разряды числа уже обработаны, - выводим результат
        if ( 0 == order )
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++ )
            {
                System.out.print ( args[i] ) ;
            }
            System.out.println () ;
            return ;
        }

        // обрабатываем текущую позицию
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            // создаем новый массив с числовыми значениями позиций для следующдего уровня
            // number = new int []{args, i}
            // p.s. да лучше было бы использовать System.arraycopy, но так нагляднее
            final long[] value = new long[args.length + 1] ;
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < args.length ; j++ )
            {
                value[j] = args[j] ;
            }
            value[args.length] = i ;

            // проверяем соответствует ли число всем фильтрам
            boolean suitable = true ;
            for ( final Filter filter : filters )
            {
                if ( !filter.suite ( value ) )
                {
                    suitable = false ;

                    // выходим из цикла проверки, -
                    // нет смысла проверять остальные, число уже не подходит
                    break ;
                }
            }

            // пропускаем числа которые не соответствуют
            if ( !suitable )
            {
                continue ;
            }

            // спускаемся вниз. к следующему разряду числа 
            find ( filters, order - 1, value ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В этой задаче проще считать количество хороших чисел. Пусть `g(n)` - количество чисел из `n` цифр, которые не содержат цифру `4` и цифры `13` подряд.

Как связаны `g(n)` и `g(n - 1)`? Возьмем любое число из `n - 1` цифры и припишем спереди цифру от нуля до девяти:

> ```
>          сколько среди них хороших
> 0xx...x    g(n - 1)
> 1xx...x    g(n - 1) - g(n - 2)
> 2xx...x    g(n - 1)
> 3xx...x    g(n - 1)
> 4xx...x    0
> 5xx...x    g(n - 1)
> 6xx...x    g(n - 1)
> 7xx...x    g(n - 1)
> 8xx...x    g(n - 1)
> 9xx...x    g(n - 1)
> ```

Случай `1xx...x` нуждается в разъяснении. Всего таких чисел `g(n - 1)`, но не все они правильные. Числа вида `13x...x` не подходят. А таких хороших чисел `g(n - 2)` и их надо вычесть.

Со случаем `4xx...x` - всё понятно: все такие числа плохие.

Суммируем таблицу, вручную оцениваем `n = 0`, `n = 1`:

> ```
> g(0) = 1
> g(1) = 9
> g(n) = 9 * g(n - 1) - g(n - 2), n >= 2
> ```

Зная количество хороших чисел легко вычислить количество плохих:

> ```
> b(n) = 10^n - g(n)
> ```

Переборные решения работают за `10^n`. Формула для `b` - за `n`. В исходной задаче `10^n = 100000` и перебор быстрый. Выигрыш по времени растёт с ростом `n`.

```
public class Without_4_13 {
    public static long pow(long b, int n) {
        long p = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            p *= b;
        }
        return p;
    }

    public static long g(int n) {
        long a = 1;
        long b = 9;
        for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; ++i) {
            long c = 9 * b - a;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
        return b;
    }
    
    public static long b(int n) {
        return pow(10, n) - g(n);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (int n = 1; n < 19; ++n) {
            System.out.println(n + " " + b(n));
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac Without_4_13.java && java Without_4_13 
> 1 1
> 2 20
> 3 289
> 4 3681
> 5 43840
> 6 500879
> 7 5564071
> 8 60575760
> 9 649617769
> 10 6885984161
> 11 72324239680
> 12 754032172959
> 13 7813965316951
> 14 80571655679600
> 15 827330935799449
> 16 8465406766515441
> 17 86361329962839520
> 18 878786562899040239
> ```

И даже это ещё не самое быстрое решение. В формуле для `g` зависимость от предыдущих значений линейная. Можно переписать её в матричном виде и применить быстрое возведение в степень. Станет быстрее настолько, что тормозить будет возведение десятки в степень, которое тоже надо будет переписать на быстрое. Всё это имеет смысл только если `long` для результата заменить на `BigInteger` и работать с действительно большими `n`.

Answer (score 0):

а можно и так!!!

```java
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j != 0; j = j / 10) {
        int a = j % 10;
        if (a == 4) {
            count++;
            break;
        }
        int b = (j / 10) % 10;
        int answ = (b * 10) + a;
        if (answ == 13) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 99; i >= 1; i = i - 1) {
        for (int s = i; s != 0; s = s / 10) {
            if (s == (4 | 13) || s % 10 == 4
                    || (s % 10 == 3 && Math.floor(s / 10) % 10 == 1)) {
                counter = counter + 1;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```