# Алгоритм для подсчета ошибочных табличек

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как составить алгоритм по заданию или блок-схему?

Задание:

> В городе N есть большой склад на котором существует 50000 различных полок. Для удобства работников руководство склада решило заказать для каждой полки табличку с номером от 00001 до 50000 в местной типографии, но когда таблички напечатали, оказалось что печатный станок из-за неисправности не печатал цифру 2, поэтому все таблички, в номерах которых содержалась одна или более двойка (например, 00002 или 20202) — надо перепечатывать. Напишите программу, которая подсчитает сколько всего таких ошибочных табличек оказалось в бракованной партии.

Comment: @turtles все эти ваши учебные задания и называются учебными, чтобы вы их решали или хотя бы пытались.

Comment: @turtles, помнится вы искали учителя по Java. Рекомендую взглянуть на [blackbeltfactory.com][1]. Этот сайт предлагает прохождение учебных курсов под руководством наставника. Каждый курс заканчивается экзаменом.

[1]:http://blackbeltfactory.com

Comment: Спасибо за полезную ссылку "Nofate"

Comment: И еще: тут принято не брать никнейм в кавычки, а ставить перед ним собачку (@). Так парсер сможет выделить  никнейм и вставить ссылку на профиль.

Comment: @karbachinsky. ответ не может быть 28. А как же учесть весь ряд чисел 2х, 2хх, 2ххх, 2хххх ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Алгоритм исключения ненужных чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37074/)

Вам же в ответ на ваш же пост аналогичную задачу объяснили. Эта даже проще - здесь только одно число и надо считать не те номера которые остались, а те которые выбыли. Сколько можно по всем подряд форумам спамить все подряд свои учебные задачи?

http://www.javatalks.ru/ftopic26300/

http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=883775

Comment: зачем же так грубо? все равно администрация почистит

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы понять закономерность. рассмотрим более простые примеры.

На более простом примере: Пусть табличек всего 50...Варианты с двойкой:
02
20
22

Пусть Табличек всего 500, варианты с двойкой:
002
020
022
202
220
222

Общая формула:
Для N позиций получаем формулу: 2^N - (N-1).

Таким образом, для 50000 N = 5  =>  Ответ: 28
Вроде бы так.

Задачка была бы по-сложнее, если бы, например, не напечатались числа 7 :)

Comment: Пусть табличек всего 50. Варианты с двойкой: `02, 12, 22, 32, 42,20, 21, 23, ...29` Итого 14.